# Unable to get a Value from Binlist API

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I was unable to get any Value from Binlist API and got an Empty Response.
I have a data Class to hold the data i have an Api Interface to get using a dynamic url and a retrofit builder 
Then a MainActivity to make use of Call to show the result of the database but unfortunately i got and empty value , it was through the onResponse

**Code**

```
   data class brand(val brand:String)
   data class Scheme(val scheme:String)
   data class Type(val type:String)
   data class Prepaid(val prepaid:Boolean)
   data class Country(val name:String , val emoji:String , val latitude:String , val longitude:String)
   data class Bank(val name:String , val url:String , val phone :String , val city:String)

interface ApiInterface {
   @GET
   fun getNumbre(@Url url:String):Call<Numbre>

   @GET
   fun getBrand(@Url url:String):Call<brand>

   @GET
   fun getScheme(@Url url:String):Call<Scheme>


   companion object {
       fun create(): ApiInterface {
           val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
               .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .baseUrl("https://lookup.binlist.net/")
               .build()

           return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
       }

   }  



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


   private var disposable: Disposable? = null
    val apiInterface: ApiInterface? = null
   private var myCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable? = null



   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


       btn_search.setOnClickListener {
           if (edit_search.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
              loadData(edit_search.text.toString())
           }
       }




   }

   private val ApiServe by lazy {
       ApiInterface.create()
   }



   private fun loadData(searchString: String) {
       ApiServe.getScheme("https://lookup.binlist.net/${searchString}").enqueue(object :Callback<Scheme>{
           override fun onFailure(call: Call<Scheme>, t: Throwable) {
               Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity , "Failed" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }

           override fun onResponse(call: Call<Scheme>, response: Response<Scheme>) {
               Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity , " response ${response.isSuccessful}" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

           }

       })


   }



}
```

Comment: Seems everything ok. I've copied your code and ran. I've searched with `45717360` and returns a value.

Comment: Please what value are you getting hope is not "response false "

Comment: I'm getting "visa" from API response and 'response true" is showing in toast.